# How to replace all files with a specific pixel size, and keep their names?

Tags: windows, batch-file, replace

I have a .png file and a folder with multiple folders in it, that all contain multiple .png files, e.g. '1.png', '2.png' and so on. What I'd like to do is to replace the contents of all those files to the first named file, but keep their names.

I'm pretty sure this is doable and I think I found an answer to do this in one folder using command prompt on Windows, but I'd also like to only replace files that have a specific file size (in pixels, and not the same size as the file I'm replacing them to, just a specific file size).

I prefer to do this simply using a batch file, so if anyone can help that'd be appreciated a lot. If it's not possible to meet the file size criteria with a batch file, but it is possible to do this for a whole directory tree with .png files, that gets me a long way as well.

Thank you in advance!

**Edit: In the comments Stephan mentioned you can't get the pixel size of a file, so it turns out this isn't possible. I'm not going to bother with an external application.**

Comment: StackOverflow is not a free code/script writing service, so you have to do your own research, share your efforts and ask a specific question. Read at least the [tour] and learn [ask]! Also check out this: [mcve]

Comment: You need to post the batch file content you found and tried with a full explanation about how it has failed to achieve your intent. You do that by [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49454805/edit)ing your question, and format your code correctly by highlighting it and pressing the button which looks like this, `{}`.

Comment: Starting point: [`for /R`](http://ss64.com/nt/for_r.html), [`copy`](http://ss64.com/nt/copy.html) and [`~` modifiers](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)

Comment: there is no command to get the pixel size; you need an external application for that.

Comment: That was the information I was looking for Stephan, so thank you a lot. I'm sorry if I didn't express my question correctly, sometimes I'm very bad with words.